# Where can I find binary (alpha) builds of the Monero GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, build

I would like help testing the Monero GUI, but can't compile it under MacOS. Are there anywhere binary builds of the Monero GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, there are not any compiled alpha GUI binaries.

That being said, when such binaries exist, the only *safe* places to download said binaries from are:

- Github - https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases
- getmonero.org - https://getmonero.org/downloads/

One last possibility is the stickied posts on https://reddit.com/r/monero, but use all normal precautions when downloading from untrusted sites.

Personally, I would not trust any links outside of these locations.

As for an ETA on binaries you can download? Soon™, as they say...